# Rails add nested attribute id to form which leads to mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

Strange! When I use `fields_for` to declare a nested attribute field, rails adds a hidden attribute with the id of the nested attribute (to perform an update):

```
= form_for @opinion do |f|
    = f.fields_for :client do |client_f|
        = client_f.text_field :name
```

Gives me:

```
<input name="opinion[client_attributes][name]" type="text" />
<input name="opinion[client_attributes][id]" type="hidden" value="4" />
```

This leads to:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: client_attributes
```

Of course, here are my models :

```
class Opinion < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :content
    attr_accessible :client_id

    validates :content, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 2048 }

    belongs_to :client
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :client

end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name

    validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 64 }

    has_many :opinions

end
```

Is is a problem with the rails view, or a model problem ?

Any idea how to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `:client_attributes` into  `:attr_accessible`

`:attr_accessible` is used to identify which fields are opened for mass-assignment.

In the request you send to controller, there should be a parameter key called `client_attributes` to group the  details of clients. You must make this one enable for mass-assignment so you can put the details of clients to update in the way of mass-assignment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that this is automatically done by `accepts_nested_attributes`.

Comment: It just "adds" the nested attribute :)